# Слайдер на весь экран!

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, всплывающее-окно, слайдер

Добрый день!
Ситуация такая: на сайте есть окошко (div) в котором крутится слайдер. При нажатии на кнопочку окошко со слайдером разворачивается во весь экран. И все бы хорошо, только вот беда, после разворачивания во весь экран слайдер ведет себя странно, а именно, неправильно отображает картинки. Такое ощущение что "запутался в размерах". Но стоит нажать Ctrl+Scroll (немножко крутануть колесико при зажатом Ctrl) и все отображается как надо! Пожалуйста, подскажите если кто знает, как вылечить??? Замучился уже, второй день сижу. Ссылка ниже. Код выложу если надо.
http://funbookforkids.com/admin/030-pagination.html

Таким образом разворачиваю:

```html
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $('#modal_open').click( function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#overlay').fadeIn(200, 
    function(){ 
    $('.linsmob') 
     .css('display', 'block') 
     .animate({opacity: 1}, 200);
    $('.swiper-container').appendTo('.linsmob');
    $('#modal_open').css('display', 'none');
  });
 });
 

$('#modal_close').click( function(){ 
  $('.linsmob')
   .animate({opacity: 0}, 200, 
    function(){ 
     $(this).css('display', 'none'); 
     $('#overlay').fadeOut(200);
     $('.swiper-container').appendTo('.m_cnt');
     $('#modal_open').css('display', 'block');
    }
   );
 });

});
```

Исходное положение
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должно быть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Лучше приведите код, а также, если необходимо, скриншоты, демонстрирующие проблему. Здесь не очень любят ссылки на сторонние сайты. Да и вопрос без кода вряд ли будет чем-то полезен другим участникам сообщества.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечный вариант реализации - проверил,работает, таймаут в зависимости от того как долго у вас анимация проходит.

```js
$('#modal_open').click(function(){
setTimeout(function(){
function resizeHandler(e) {
    console.log(e.type + ' triggered.');
}

window.addEventListener('resize', resizeHandler);

var resizeEvent = new Event('resize');
window.dispatchEvent(resizeEvent);
},300)
})
```

Comment: Спасибо ОГРОМНОЕ!!! Сейчас попробую. Просто мне тайм аут не  нужен. Сразу, кликнул - развернулось!

Comment: @zfiodor Таймаут всётаки нужен,ибо у вас ресайз может сработать раньше чем слайдер откроется в полном формате. Я бы оставил. Одобряйте вариант ответа если решено.

Comment: У меня что то не получается... Может я что то не так вставляю?..
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $('#modal_open').click(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
  function resizeHandler(e) {
   console.log(e.type + ' triggered.');
  }
  
  window.addEventListener('m_cnt', resizeHandler);
  
  var resizeEvent = new Event('m_cnt');
  window.dispatchEvent(resizeEvent);
  }, 300)
  });

Comment: При клике ничего не происходит а в консоли пишет ".m_cnt triggered" и все!

Comment: @zfiodor я вам дал уже готовый код , ничего менять не надо,проверил в трёх браузерах , всё работает.

Comment: Еще раз вставил, безо всяких изменений, как есть. При клике снова ничего а в консоли "resize triggered."

Comment: Я прошу прощения!!! Я с дуру удалил свой код который выводил картинку! Сейчас все СУПЕР!!! Спасибо огромное за помощь! Просто у меня после двух дней голова уже не варит. Еще раз простите и СПАСИБО!